# Positive feedback loop in the Wien oscillator

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, oscillator, feedback

Let's say you got this circuit given which works as a Wien oscillator. To my understanding here Ri is the negative feedback loop and the total impedance of R3 & R4 & L2 & R1 are the feedback loop.

To get the total complex power consumed by the positive feedback loop, I assumed to use the formula: S = [(Vo - Vi)(Vo - Vi)°] / Z°(positive feedback loop)

( with ° meaning the complex conjugate )

However I keep getting the wrong answers, so is there another way to calculate the complex power in the positive feedback loop?

[image: schematic]

Comment: The op amp input terminals are labeled the wrong way around.

Comment: Use dots on connections where lines cross. Better still, don't cross wires if they are to be connected.

Comment: A circuit I never have sen up to now. Question: Did it work? What are the resistor values in both loops? Such a circuit (with resistive possitive feedback) works only with a kind of notch in the negative feedback loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you have mis-labeled positive and negative loops. Ri is in the positive loop, not the negative one.